# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 from SQL Server Management studio or Toad for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have been Using SQL Server 2008 R2 database for quite sometime. All was working fine till two days back w.r.t connecting the database from SQL Server Management studio. Now if I try to connect, it keeps on connecting and it never shows me connected database in Object Explorer. Same thing happens when I try to connect using Toad for SQL Server.

[Image showing connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oScqO.png)

However I am able to connect the same database (which is installed on my local machine) from my peer's SQL Server Management studio and he was able to access that database properly. Also I am able to connect the same database from my web application (which is also installed on my local machine) and also from Eclipse --> Database Development plugin.

I even reinstalled just the SQL Server Management Studio (I haven't uninstalled MSSQLSERVER during this) and tried again, yet it was showing the same result.

Also currently in the client protocols, Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled.

Please let me know if anyone has come across this strange problem and really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you ping the SQL Server computer from your computer?

Comment: The SQL Server that I am trying to use is installed in my local machine itself.

Comment: (local) will be using named pipes, your friends PC is probably using hostname or IP address which uses TCP. What happens if you specify the hostname instead of (local) in your SSMS? (assuming you have the correct instance etc)

Comment: Even if I use my IP address or 127.0.0.1, it behaves in the same manner when I try to connect.